# Is this possible? Check cell value if >0 move to next cell. Repeat until cell = 0, return last non-zero cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a function that checks a cells value, and if that cell value is >0 it moves to the cell below, and checks that cell. Once it finds a cell that is not greater than zero then it posts the last cells value that was greater than zero. 
i.e. C39 = 400 move to cell C40. C40 = 440 move to cell C41. C41 = 0, return cell value of C40.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: so you want to return the cell right above the first `0` in Column C?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: `=IF(A2=<0,A1,"")` and drag down

Comment: You had this tagged both excel and google sheets, please choose one.  currently google sheets has been chosen for you.  If that is an error please change to the Excel tag.  But choose one as they are different enough that many answers will not work in both.

Comment: Scott, yes sir.

Comment: player0 what I'm doing a mileage tracking sheet, and I want the end odometer number for the last day of the month to post in a cell at the top of the sheet, but since different have different numbers of days, I want the sheet to check the last 3 cells for an ending odometer value. So, if there is a value in say C29, then I want it to check C30 to see if there is a value there, if there is, I want it to check C31, and if there isn't a value there, then I want it to post the last cell that had a positive number, in this example C30. Hope that makes sense, suuuper new at excel and sheets.

Comment: I meant different months have different numbers of days. lol sorry

Comment: It is google sheets @ScottCraner

Comment: =IFS((D37 > 0) AND (D38 > 0, (D39 > 0)), D39, [ ((D37 > 0) AND((D38 > 0),(D39 = 0))), D38 ], [ ((D37 > 0) AND ((D38 = 0))), D37 ])    This was my best guess at trying to get it to work, but no luck... Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(
  A:A,
  MIN(
    IFNA(MATCH(0, A:A, 0) - 1, ROWS(A:A)),
    IFNA(MATCH(True, A:A = "", 0) - 1, ROWS(A:A))
  )
)
```

This formula will return a cell with the minimal row number that is before the 1st 0, or it is before the first blank cell, or if there are no 0 and no blank cells it will return the last cell in a column.

Change `A:A` to `C:C` or whatever column you need.

[image]